# UTF-8 characters from MariaDB, Drupal, php

Tags: php, mysql, json, unicode, drupal

So i have MARIADB Clustered DB where my charset is set to : utf8_general_ci

I also have PHP function inside of Drupal Module what DB_Selects rows and in the end returnes them as "JSON".

And the problem is that it returns UTF-8 Characters with encoding, but they should be decoded..

example : Ü is returned as : \u00dc

php Function what i have

```
function jgid_response($field, $id) {
  drupal_add_http_header("Expires", -1);
  drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE);

  $res = db_select('TABLE1', 'ur')
    ->fields('ur', array('Cust_id', 'User_id'));

  $res->addExpression('IF(begin > 0, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(begin), \'%d.%m.%Y\'), 0)', 'begin');
  $res->addExpression('IF(end > 0, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(end), \'%d.%m.%Y\'), 0)', 'end');
  $res->join('TABLE2', 'PERSON', 'person.id = ur.Cust_id');
  $res->join('TABLE2', 'COMPANY', 'company.id = ur.User_id');

  $res->fields('person', array('firstName', 'lastName'));
  $res->fields('company', array('name'));

  $res->condition($field, $id)
      ->condition('ur.notActive', 0);

  $string = (string) $res;

  $res = $res->execute();

  if ($res->rowCount() > 0) {
    $data = array();

    while ($result = $res->fetchObject()) {

      $result->application = 'APPLICATION_NAME';

      $data[] = $result;
    }

    return array(
      'result' => 'OK',
      'list' => $data,
    );
  }
}
```

Is there any way how to force that array to encoded chars?
i have tryed :
JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES and also JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

also tryed to add :

```
drupal_add_http_header("X-JSON-RESPONSE", 1);

drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv; utf-8');
```

where am i wrong?

Comment: `\u00dc` is the perfectly acceptable JSON way to encode the character Ü…!?

Comment: Yeah, but other application what recives that JSON wants Ü not \u00dc :)

Comment: `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` should have worked unless the original source of the data had _already_ escaped it.

Comment: The other app does not use a compliant JSON parser…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON with escaped Unicode characters is valid. You didn't show us where your php program serializes the JSON. The built-in php [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method generates it that way.

[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in your browser should give you back data with proper unicode representation.

Notice that you can't affect the way JSON is encoded by using Content-Type or other headers. Why not?  JSON itself dictates its internal format.

Due to its history from before the dawn of Unicode, php generally uses `/u` style encoding where it can.

Comment: I have to search a bit, i am new on Drupal and this module is made by someone else. It is a "Custom module" and i have to "teach" my self how they work. easy on Joomla / WP, Drupal seems to be a bit more complicated :).